# Styling select tags using CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to styling the select tags for this image below
[image]

I was able to custom the dropdown (code below):

```
select {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 130%;
  border-radius: .2em;
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  color: #181820;
  
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  
  background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-vol-1-4/24/dropdown_arrow-512.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px;
  background-position: right;
  background-origin: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Here you can find the solution to it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: @NikhilSingh it said only `<select>` not <'option>` I was looking how to style `option` so far `select` only can be styled in CSS

Comment: @sagar thanks, i found that it cannot be styled using CSS on mozilla too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really. Check this snippet from mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

> The `<select>` element is notoriously difficult to style productively with CSS. You can affect certain aspects like any element — for example, manipulating the box model, the displayed font, etc., and you can use the appearance property to remove the default system appearance.
>
> However, these properties don't produce a consistent result across browsers, and it is hard to do things like line different types of form element up with one another in a column. The `<select>` element's internal structure is complex, and hard to control. If you want to get full control, you should consider using a library with good facilities for styling form widgets, or try rolling your own dropdown menu using non-semantic elements, JavaScript, and WAI-ARIA to provide semantics.

Do indeed check the advanced guide for the little you can do to style them. A good example of how bad styling is for options:

> You'll notice that the options don't inherit the font set on the parent. You also can't consistently set things like spacing and colors. For example, Firefox will apply color and background-color when set on the `<option>` elements, Chrome won't. Neither of them will apply any kind of spacing